# Yii - Download Gridview As PDF

Tags: php, pdf, gridview, yii, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel 1.8.0 I have used eexcelview and tlbexcelview for downloading gridview as excel and csv, it works fine.
But when I try to download as PDF it does not function. First I was getting an error:

```
PDF Rendering library has not been defined.
```

Then after reading some blogs I got to know that I have to change settings.php in PHPExcel and let it know that which provider I have to use. so I changed this code in settings.php:

```
/**
 * Name of the external Library used for rendering PDF files
 *  e.g.
 *          mPDF
 *
 * @var string
 */
private static $_pdfRendererName = 'mPDF';
```

So after this I am getting this error:

```
include(PHPExcel_Writer_PDF_mPDF.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

PHPExcel/Writer/PDF/mPDF.php does exist there

Can anyone please guide me what are the exact changes I need to do and in which files. If anyone of you would have setup this before in eexcelview or tlbexcelview you could easily guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `PHPExcel/Writer/PDF/mPDF.php` file?

Comment: ya it does exist and it came with the PHPExcel package it seems. I have mPDF saved in vendors folder

Comment: So, import theme. `Yii::import('path.*')` . user * to import all PHP files into a directory.

Comment: so I add this line in 'import' of main config 'application.vendors.MPDF57.*' Still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used PHPExcel version 1.7.7 which comes with a PDF renderer libraray and it works fine.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: how did you use it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import this class to use.  You can either call `Yii::import()` in each use or set the class on import of app main config.

Comment: I need to know how to set path so PHPExcel knows which PDF rendering library I want to use and where is mPDF.php saved

Comment: instead of `$_pdfRendererName = 'mPDF'`, have you tried `$_pdfRendererName = Yii::getPathOfAlias(' 'application.vendors.MPDF57.PHPExcel_Writer_PDF_mPDF');` or something like that?

Comment: there is no file like PHPExcel_Writer_PDF_mPDF.. there is a file in location PHPExcel/Writer/PDF/mPDF.php

Comment: well...that's why this doesn't work, right? even if you include the mPdf class properly, that won't work...I don't nkow too much about the PHPExcel, but seems you'll need to pass the full path to the mPdf, using the getPathOfAlias or not. Otherwise, it will try to include that crazy PHPExcel_Writer_PDF_mPDF

Comment: ya it has to replace the _ with DIRECTORY SEPERATOR but because of some autoload issue it is not doing it

Comment: Yii overrides thedefault autoload in some cases, but i don't know if this is the problem...I would look for help here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/101/how-to-use-phpexcel-external-library-with-yii/

Comment: i already looked at it and followed the steps.. still no success

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54455/discussion-between-neophyte-and-vschettino).